# Is a finitely generated non-abelian group embedded in a semidirect product of a torsion group and a torsion-free group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finitely-generated, semidirect-product

Let $G$ be a finitely generated group and $Tor(G)$ the subgroup generated by all torsion elements of $G$. Then $G/Tor(G)$ is torsion-free. In the abelian case we have

*Every finitely generated abelian group is the direct product of its torsion subgroup and of a torsion-free subgroup*

Can we say something in the non-abelian case? Specifically, I would like to know if $G$ is embedded in $Tor(G) \rtimes H$ for a subgroup $H \simeq G/Tor(G)$.

Comment: You seem to be assuming, incorrectly, that the set of torsion elements forms a subgroup - this is not true in general, and this leads to counter-examples to your question.

Comment: @user1729 He's defining $\operatorname{Tor}(G)$ to be the subgroup *generated by* the torsion elements. I think he's aware that the torsion elements don't necessarily form a subgroup.

Comment: However, is it true that $G/\operatorname{Tor}(G)$ is torsion-free? For example, if $G$ has presentation $\langle a,b\mid a^2, (ab^2)^2\rangle$, then $a$ and $ab^2$ are torsion elements, so $b^2=(a^{-1})(ab^2)\in\operatorname{Tor}(G)$, but I don't see why $b\in\operatorname{Tor}(G)$, although I may be missing something. And if it's not, then $b$ represents an order two element of $G/\operatorname{Tor}(G)$.

Comment: @JeremyRickard The length of the chain $G=G_0\to G_1\to G_n\cdots$, where $G_{i+1}=G_i/\operatorname{Tor}(G_i)$ is sometimes called the *torsion-length* of $G$. See, for example, https://arxiv.org/abs/2112.14546v3.

Comment: Just to clarify, you are viewing $\operatorname{Tor}(G)\rtimes H$ as a subgroup of $G$? i.e. the sequence $1\to\operatorname{Tor}(G)\to G\to G/\operatorname{Tor}(G)\to1$ does not necessarily split, but you're taking some subgroup $H\leq G$ where the restriction does split? (If so, then the answer is "no", but I want to check I'm understanding it properly...)

Comment: The question in the title of the post is clear, and the answer is no, because the torsion elements do not in general form a subgroup.

Comment: While the subgroup generated by torsion elements is indeed normal, it is in general false that $G/\mathrm{Tor}(G)$ is torsionfree, because $\mathrm{Tor}(G)$ may contain elements that are not torsion. Consider the group $G=\{a,b,c\mid a^2=b^2=1, ba=abc^2\}$. This is obtained by first taking $C_2*C_2$, and then adding a square root of $[b,a]$; that latter is not torsion (the only torsion elements of $C_2*C_2$ are conjugates of powers of $a$ or of $b$), but lies in $\mathrm{Tor}(G)$. The element $c$ is not in $\mathrm{Tor}(G)$, but has order $2$ in $G/\mathrm{Tor}(G)$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I see. Thank you (and another guys) for the comment!